# Checkbox Selections seem to disagree with each other

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Ok I've been given a project to work on using JavaScript (still learning).
Basically I need to have a list of checkboxes (that are attributes) that users can select, as they select these different attributes I need to have a different divs display that have corresponding info to the selected attributes. e.g. if they select the "Economy" checkbox, only the divs that are associated with that checkbox display. That much I've been able to get to work.

Now I need to get the attributes that don't go together to grey out and become disabled depenind on the checked attribute. e.g. the "Economy" checkbox doesn't go with the "Premium" checkbox. So if the user would check the "Economy" checkbox the "Premium" one should be come disabled and greyed out. To an extent I've gotten that to work.

BUT, some of the attributes are shared by different divs. That is where I'm having my troubles. here is my HTML: I do have a link in the 'head' to my js file.
This is just a section of the page:

```
    <div id="column2" style="width:250px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; float:left">
    <form name="checkForm2" id="checkForm2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_9" name="att_9" onChange="showBERNINI();"><span id="grey_att9">Economy</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_10" name="att_10" onChange="showPICASSO();"><span id="grey_att10">Visible Banner: 33.5" x 78.7"</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_11" name="att_11" onChange="showMATISSE();"><span id="grey_att11">Tension Knob System</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_12" name="att_12" onChange="showBERNPIC();"><span id="grey_att12">Tape-in Bottom Rail</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_13" name="att_13" onChange="showPICASSO();"><span id="grey_att13">3 piece bungee pole</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_14" name="att_14" onChange="showMATISSE();"><span id="grey_att14">Great for interchangeable graphics</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_15" name="att_15" onChange="showBERNINI();"><span id="grey_att15">90 day warranty</span><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="att_16" name="att_16" onChange="showMATISSE();"><span id="grey_att16">Chrome end caps</span><br />
    </form>
</div>
```

---

JS file:

```
function showBERNINI() {
if (document.checkForm1.att_2.checked || document.checkForm1.att_5.checked || document.checkForm1.att_6.checked || document.checkForm2.att_9.checked || document.checkForm2.att_15.checked || document.checkForm3.att_23.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Picasso").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("att_3").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_10").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_13").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_22").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_24").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("grey_att3").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att10").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att13").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att22").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att24").style.color="#d1d1d1";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("Picasso").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("att_3").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_10").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_13").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_22").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_24").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("grey_att3").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att10").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att13").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att22").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att24").style.color="";
}
if (document.checkForm2.att_12.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
}}

function showPICASSO() {
if (document.checkForm1.att_3.checked || document.checkForm2.att_10.checked || document.checkForm2.att_13.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Bernini").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("att_2").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_5").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_6").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_9").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_15").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_23").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("grey_att2").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att5").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att6").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att9").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att15").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att23").style.color="#d1d1d1";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("Bernini").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("att_2").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_5").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_6").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_9").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_15").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_23").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("grey_att2").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att5").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att6").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att9").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att15").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att23").style.color="";
}
if (document.checkForm2.att_12.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="#d1d1d1";
}
if (document.checkForm3.att_22.checked || document.checkForm3.att_24.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Bernini").style.display="none";
}}

function showBERNPIC() {
if (document.checkForm2.att_12.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="#d1d1d1";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="#d1d1d1";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="";
    document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("grey_att11").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att14").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att16").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att17").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att18").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att19").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att20").style.color="";
    document.getElementById("grey_att21").style.color="";
}
if (document.checkForm1.att_2.checked || document.checkForm1.att_5.checked || document.checkForm1.att_6.checked || document.checkForm2.att_9.checked || document.checkForm2.att_15.checked || document.checkForm3.att_23.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Picasso").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
}
if (document.checkForm1.att_3.checked || document.checkForm2.att_10.checked || document.checkForm2.att_13.checked)
{
    document.getElementById("Bernini").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
}}
```

The best example of the issue I'm having is when I select the "Economy" checbox, then select the "Tape-in Bottom Rail" checkbox, then if I happen to deselect the "Tape-in Bottom Rail" checkbox too many checkboxes become available again, I can't get this to show only what should be with just the "Economy" checkbox selected. Its like some are being enabled that should not be.

I hope I didn't add too much here but since this is my 1st JavaScript project I figured I should post more rather than less. I also know there has to be a more consolidated way to do what I'm trying but I'm not real comfortable using jQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been staring that this for quite a while.

I'm attempting to use the getElementByClassName and having some success, but not completely. I have this html

```
<p><input type="button" value="nightmare" onClick="nightmare();"></p>
<div id="form" style="width:810px; font-family:Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
<div id="column1" style="width:250px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; float:left">
    <form name="checkForm1" id="checkForm1">
        <span class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="att_1" name="att_1" class="all" onChange="">Single-sided</span><br />
        <span class="bernini"><input type="checkbox" id="att_2" name="att_2" onChange="">Visible Banner: 33.5" x 36"-78.7"</span><br />
        <span class="picasso"><input type="checkbox" id="att_3" name="att_3" onChange="">Medium Duty Spring System</span><br />
        <span class="matisse"><input type="checkbox" id="att_4" name="att_4" onChange="">Clip-in Top Rail</span><br />
        <span class="bernini"><input type="checkbox" id="att_5" name="att_5" onChange="">Adjustable Twist Locking Pole</span><br />
        <span class="bernini"><input type="checkbox" id="att_6" name="att_6" onChange="">Single graphic use</span><br />
        <span class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="att_7" name="att_7" onChange="">Carrying case included</span><br />
        <span class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="att_8" name="att_8" onChange="">Silver finish</span><br />
    </form>
</div></div>
```

and this js

```
function nightmare(){var berninis = document.getElementsByClassName('picasso matisse');for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {berninis[i].style.color="#d1d1d1";}}
```

Now if I just have just 1 class in the function it works but as soon as I do both classes it no longer works.

Comment: use jquery for do this

Comment: Your checks are too simplistic. You cannot check just the checkbox that was changed but all the checkboxes that apply to a given attribute. That is you always need to be checking every checkbox that applies to a given attribute whenever any checkbox that applies to that attribute changes. Checking just the one changed checkbox fails the way you've seen.

Comment: All of those `getElementById` could be replaced with `getElementsByClassName` and a simple loop.

Comment: I thought I was checking that unless I'm missing it. Is the (document.checkForm... line check all the attributes associated with that checkbox that had that function on it?

Comment: with the getElementsByClass I can get one of the classes to change style, but not more than one. getElementsByClassName('picasso matisse') doesn't seem to work, but ('picasso') does. I also tried attaching the .disabled=true to the class and that also does not work. The searching I'm doing seems like I should be able to have multiple classes in the getElementsByClassName('class1 class2').

Answer (score 0):

if you know about angular, you could use it to simplify your work. To use it, there are a lot of information you can use to help you with that and is very simple to learn. In this framework, you can create your functions and you simply define them in the beginning of code, for example . In .js file, you simply have the action you want, and prevents all of your work and code. This is a very good advice to work in this kind of stuff.